# group_by and coercing to time series dplyr r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(region = rep(c("a","b","c","d"),12),
                 group = rep(c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","D","D","D"),12), 
                 num = rep(c(1:12),12))
```

And I want to group by region, then by group, and coerce num into a time series object - I am doing this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(region,group) %>%
  mutate(num = ts(num,f=4))
```

And it works, but I get a whole bunch of warnings that read:

```
12: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
Vectorizing 'ts' elements may not preserve their attributes
```

In reality I am applying this to a large data.frame and need to decompose the time series data. I am using stl to do so, in my simplified example:

```
df %>% 
group_by(region,group) %>%
mutate(num = ts(num,f=4)) %>% 
mutate(trendcycle(stl(num, s.window = "per")))
```

but I get an error saying:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: series is not periodic or has less than two periods.
```

I'm guessing that this has to do with trying to coerce the data to ts format. The thing is, I have previously been able to do this with no problems.

I am using R 3.4.1 and dplyr 0.7.1

Comment: I have gotten around the issue by including the ts conversion into one mutate call as below:

   df %>% 
   group_by(region,group) %>% 
   mutate(trendcycle(stl(ts(num,f=4), s.window = "per"))))

Comment: You can post that as a solution

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten around the issue by including the ts conversion into one mutate call as below:

```
df %>%
group_by(region,group) %>%
mutate(trendcycle(stl(ts(num,f=4), s.window = "per")))
```

I got here by attacking the problem with data.table:

```
df1 <- setDT(df)[,trendcycle(stl(ts(num, frequency = 4), s.window ="per")), by = .(region,group)]
```

Which was faster, but my program follows the tidyverse syntax, so I am keeping things consistent